# Skipping na values while reading a csv or excel file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a csv file which has three columns. I will be using first two columns as multiindex and the third column will be a column value in the dataframe.

Raw CSV sample:

```
index1,index2,value
a1,b1,20
a1,b2,10
a1,b3,40
a2,b1,10
a2,b2,
a2,b3,30
a2,b4,40
```

Now while reading the csv, the row for a2,b2 is read and inferred as NaN. Which is correct. But can I not read that row at all?

Right now, I am doing this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv').dropna()
```

This will remove that a2-b2 line from the final dataframe.

But then when I use `df.index.levels[0]` or `df.index.levels[1]`, it still shows a2-b2 combination.
I will be iterating through the dataframe one item at a time from level 0 index (level 1 all items included). So basically, each item in level 0 for my dataframe becomes a subset of dataframe. And then I run calculations and create charts through that. I also use those index values as labels in the chart.

So, I need to get those index values only which are actually in the dataframe (post dropping).

How to do that?

Question:

1. Is it possible to NOT READ entire row if column='value' has NaN value?
2. If that is not possible, can I get the index items list of only those items that have value in the dataframe? (I mean if a index item is dropped using dropna, then it should not appear in the df.index.levels or df.index.get_level_names. Can we do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv').dropna()

for idx, row in df.pivot_table('value', 'index1', 'index2', aggfunc='sum').iterrows():
    row.dropna().plot.bar(title=idx)
    plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

---

You can't use each levels separately.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=['index1', 'index2']).dropna()
print(df)

# Output
               value
index1 index2       
a1     b1       20.0
       b2       10.0
       b3       40.0
a2     b1       10.0
       b3       30.0
       b4       40.0
```

```
>>> df.index.levels[0]
Index(['a1', 'a2'], dtype='object', name='index1')

>>> df.index.levels[1]
Index(['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'], dtype='object', name='index2')

>>> df.index
MultiIndex([('a1', 'b1'),
            ('a1', 'b2'),
            ('a1', 'b3'),
            ('a2', 'b1'),
            ('a2', 'b3'),
            ('a2', 'b4')],
           names=['index1', 'index2'])
```

If you use a loop you have to use the latter:

```
for (idx1, idx2), row in df.iterrows():
    print(idx1, idx2)

a1 b1
a1 b2
a1 b3
a2 b1
a2 b3
a2 b4
```

**Tip**: you can use `get_level_values`:

```
>>> df.index.get_level_values('index1')  # or 0
Index(['a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2'], dtype='object', name='index1')
 
>>> df.index.get_level_values('index2')  # or 1
Index(['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b1', 'b3', 'b4'], dtype='object', name='index2')
```

Comment: No no. See, I will first filter the dataframe to one value in level 0. So the dataframe will be first three rows for a1. Now ignore a1, and create a bar chart for b1, b2 b3 with corresponding values. And name xticks as b1, b2, b3.
Then move to a2. Again filtering will give you rows last three rows. Do the same thing and create a chart for b1, b3, b4 with corresponding values.

I want to do this inside a for loop. For each item in level 0, create chart. like that.

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: Thanks @Corralien. However, I will go with another way, as I do not have know the value for  column names and index names. I want to dynamically get it from the dataframe. So, I do not want the code to specifically use any of these names.